# Please provide communities with custom post-delete-reasons as a moderation tool

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, deleted-posts

Communities (or rather their moderators as representatives of us) can currently set three custom post-close-reasons — in the same manner, I would welcome custom post-delete-reasons as a moderation tool that would quickly point janitors towards the correct direction regarding routine work.
A custom comment will always draw potential unnecessary adversaries and requires additional work by other flag handlers in the queues.

For example:

> This post seems to be AI-generated, violating community guidelines.

Custom post-delete-reasons would, as general post-delete-reasons already do, facilitate less intrusive and laser-focused communication between janitors for community-specific problems.

Answer (score 4):

### Have a new, custom "post notice" created for your site, rather than the much larger development of a new actual delete reason.

This, effectively, already exists, but in a different form than you've requested. Moderators can add a "post notice" to any post. I believe the default ones are "Needs citation", "Current event", and "Needs detailed answers". Post notices for a site can be edited and/or added by Stack Overflow staff. I've considered requesting for a "Deleted due to being AI generated content" one to be added on Stack Overflow, but have not, yet, done so.

Adding such a notice is a separate step for the moderators, rather than being directly integrated with deleting a post as you've requested. Having the underlying mechanism of what you're wanting be a post notice is substantially more likely to be implemented, as it's something that already exists within the system, rather than needing to develop a completely new "delete" methodology and burdening every delete action with making a choice between type of delete being performed. If moderators desire, a userscript could be used to have a single button for "delete and add AI post notice", but the usefulness of that will depend on the volume of posts where the post notice should be applied.

#### How to get a new, custom post notice for your site?

I'd expect the process for requesting a new post notice to added to your site would follow the normal process for requesting such customizations for a site. Usually, this is done by creating a post on your site's child meta (i.e. not here on Meta Stack Exchange) which defines the wording to be used for the post notice and requests the change. If there's support from the community, or at least from the moderators, then the meta post can have a [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) tag added to it by a moderator to escalate the request to the CMs.

Comment: A regular privileged user cannot issue post notes. They cannot use this to signal to other community members doing janitorial work. This only works for public-facing communication, which is undesirable. Post notes are a solution to a different problem and introduces more work for everyone involved.

Comment: @Akixkisu If a post is violating community guidelines and you're not a moderator, you should be flagging it that way moderators can determine what to do about the user posting such content.

Comment: @Akixkisu It's true this solution doesn't allow regular users to add such a notice (other than flagging for moderator attention asking for the notice to be added), but what you're asking for is highly unlikely to ever be implemented, as it's substantial development work, is against the philosophy of having such communications between regular users be public, substantially complicates the UI for deletion (a cost in user effort which would need to be paid *every* time someone votes to delete), and alternate methodologies to accomplish the goal exist (e.g., comments, flags, and post notices).

Comment: @Makyen I cannot evaluate that, I know a similar feature and hence have phrased my request. It is unfortunate if the state that we have to burden elected moderators every single time for something that a regular privileged user could solve with one click persists.

Comment: @RobertLongson, a low-quality, spam, etc. post-deletion-reason requires no elected moderator input. If there are more generic community-specific deletion-reasons, it would be preferable to reduce workload for elected moderators by supplying us with those as an option.